# Optimizing select in case statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following tables:

```
    deals:
    PositionID - int
    Login - int,
    VolumeClosed - int,
    Time = datetime
```

I have the following query:

```
select
    d.PositionID,
    d.login,
    case
        when d.VolumeClosed = 0 then d.Time
        else ''
    end as Open_Time,
    
    case
        when d.VolumeClosed = 0 then (
        select
            `TIME`
        from
            deals
        where
            volumeclosed <> 0
            and d.PositionID = PositionID)
        else ''
    end as Close_Time
from
    deals d
```

Is there a way to optimize the select in the Case statement ?

The result is the following:

```
"PositionID","Login","Open_Time","Close_Time"
0,250052,"2022-08-01 10:32:29",
6218368,250052,"2022-08-01 10:45:11","2022-08-01 10:45:12"
6218368,250052,"",""
6218374,250052,"2022-08-01 10:45:41","2022-08-01 10:45:42"
6218374,250052,"",""
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really have 2 case statements with the same criteria? `when d.VolumeClosed = 0`

Comment: You appear to be selecting `TIME` from a table with no such column name?

Comment: @RiggsFolly forgot to add it

Comment: It's not really helpful that your query interrogates volumeclosed but your sample data does not include it , it's also more helpful to have sample and expected outcome as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon the expected outcome is the one that I am showing in the picture, the goal here is to see if there is a way to skip that select into case query ?

Comment: OK then publish sample data as text please.

Comment: @P.Salmon okay, published as csv

Comment: Is there only 1 row for each PositionID with volumeclosed <> 0 in the table? If not, then there is a problem with your code because the subquery may return more than 1 rows and you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

This composite index on `deals` may speed up the subquery some:

```
 INDEX(PositionID,  volumeclosed, `TIME`)
```